# Windows 7 - User profile corrupted?

Tags: windows-7, icons, internet-explorer-8

Not sure if this is related to user profile corruption but I logged in today into my system and I saw 2 weird things... my IE8 icon has changed to a standard icon and if I right click on my computer and I select Manage... nothing happens.

Anyone with similar issues?

Comment: When someone helps you, you should mark their answer as a solution so they get credit for helping you. It's how this site works.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your other issues, but here is how to fix the manage issue

This is where you right click on Computer and select manage, and nothing opens, no errors, and CompMgmtLauncher may show up in task manager, but no window opens.

modify the registry.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\Manage\command]

change Default data in the command Key to:

%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s

.

Comment: Thats great Dave, please mark my post as the solution please.